# how to repeat last word of a line using notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have multiple lines in a file. I want to repeat the last word on a line with additional suffix space or tab and prefixed with `,`.

For example, the sample content of the file would look like:

```
Deepak Kumar
Deepak The powerhouse
Deepak mcapatna
```

The output file what I want is

```
Deepak Kumar kumar,
Deepak The powerhouse  powerhouse,
Deepak mcapatna mcapatna,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

**Find What**:    `(\S+)$`
**Replace with**: `$1 $1,`

**Explanation**: `(\S+)` is a capturing group that matches 1 or non-whitespace characters, and `$` is the end of the line in Notepad++.

Settings:

[image]

Comment: correct answer.only \L was not required.Its converts all the new words in lower case.Please update the answer,So that it may be useful for other user.

Comment: Great, so you used no additional operators? Please let me know to update the answer. Or did you use `\l`? I assumed you need the operators because of `Deepak Kumar -> Deepak Kumar kumar,` example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very basic regex as

```
([^ \n]+)$
```

- `([^ \n]+)` Matches anything other than space or newline. This will match the last word in the string. Captures in capture group `\1`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the device.

Specify the replace string as

```
\1 \1,
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dT3lQ6/3)

Comment: working fine for the line having two words. for the single word its adding only space ,

Comment: @mcapatna A small change in pattern would do the trick. Updated the answer.